# add file in folders with PHP

Tags: php

I have more than 100 folders with subfolders ...

example:

```
a/b/c/d/e
f/g/h
m/n
k/l/o/p/s/z/x/

....
```

I want to added a blank file (index.html) to each folder (and each subfolder). 
Could I do that with PHP? And How?

Comment: Yes you could do that. Or you could just add a single `.htaccess` file in the root directory with the `Options -Index` directive.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. (BTW I'm not lazy)

Comment: @mario If I could to that with `htaccess` I think it will be more easy. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be easier with a shell script:

```
exec('
  for DIR in $(find . -type d) ; do touch "$DIR/index.html" ; done
');
```

With PHP more effort:

```
function scandir_tree($dir) {
    $r = array("$dir");
    foreach (scandir($dir) as $fn) {
        if (is_dir("$dir/$fn") && ($fn[0] != ".")) {
            $r = array_merge($r, scandir_tree("$dir/$fn"));
        }
    }  
    return $r;
}

foreach (scandir_tree(".") as $dir) {
    touch("$dir/index.html");
}
```

Or as said, using a single [`Options -Index` via `.htaccess`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#options) to prevent the default directory list generation with Apache.

Comment: @MiniNaim: That's just shell scripting. Basically `bash` or any `sh` can execute it.

Comment: Why do it in PHP anyway. Let's throw away every programming language and just resort to batch. :s

Comment: On Windows you don't have a shellish shell. You would need to write a manual workaround. (Albeit there are similar capabilities in `CMD`)

Comment: I think I'll use `options -index`. Could you please help on that?

Comment: I loved the code, but can't figure out how to execute it on windows

Comment: Well, you just need to create a single `.htaccess` file in the root directory of that tree. And there just add the single line `Options -Index` on top. That's it.

Comment: thank you, Can I display an `index.html` file with `htaccess`

Comment: BS: I used `Options -Index` but I can't see my folders (there are hidden with this option) I won't hidden them; I need just to hide the content (images, files ...) from those folders

Comment: Also If I could execute the code on windows. I think It will be good :)

Comment: @MiniNaim: Yes true, Apache hides the complete folder structure then. Well in this case, you would need a custom script method still.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, take a look at recursion and the directory/file commands.

Take your top directory(s), iterate down through them, if necessary, only if their directory name matches a-z etc. Then open a file called index.html and save it (or copy it from a previous copy)

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that, for a specified folder:

- checks for existance of index.html using file_exists
- creates the file if needed
- uses scandir to read the contents of a specified folder
- check if each item is a file or folder (using is_dir)
- recursively calls itself for every subdirectory found.

Comment: BTW, never done anything like this in PHP. Had to lookup almost each of these functions on http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php which turned out to be not that hard at all! :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a good tutorial in writing files: [Rank and Files](http://devzone.zend.com/node/view/id/636)

and [open Dir](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php)

save your folder names in an array and loop through them using one file at a time. or opendir can give you the list of folders ans simply loop and write the files